# What does this type of Object mean?

Tags: java

```
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(json, headers);
```

I have a couple of questions here?

1. What does the `?` mean here. Why have they put `<?>` instead of `<Object>`
2. Why does the HTTPEntity Constructor take <`Object`> as its type but the Class Reference taking <`?`> as its type.

Comment: `?` is wild card type you can read it on [Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: The HttpEntity<?> at the left and the HttpEntity<Object> at the right are totally independent from each other. The only rule that links them is that an HttpEntity<Object> is also an HttpEntity<?>, which is needed for the assignment operator = to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?`-- wildcard syntax

```
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(json, headers);

`HttpEntity<?>` whose element type matches anything..
```

Remember that if you try to add Object into requestEntity you'd get a compiler error.

```
       requestEntity.add(new Object());//compiler error on this line as it expects `?` not an object
```

read about generics [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Answer (score 1):

`?` means **wild card** it a generic symbol. It means HttpEntity of unknown.